# Which solvers should I use to solve large, but extremely sparse LP problems with 100-500 thousands of variables?

Tags: sparse-matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, glpk

I would like to solve LP problems with hundreds of thousands of decision variables.
These LP problems have linear constraints which link only 2-3 variables, leading to extremely sparse coefficient matrices.
Which methods and (free) codes do you suggest for this issue?
Is there one which can start from a known feasible solution provided by the user?

Comment: Seeking library recommendations is off topic. While you still don't have code, you should move to Operations Research.

Comment: That's the best suggestion. I will repeat my quesiton on that page (I haven't known it so far) and close this one.